# Unable to see resolved component link at CDA side | DXA | web8

Tags: dxa, web8, link-resolver

I am using a component link in the rich text box.I can see the mylinktext at CMS but after publishing the component it shows only 'mylinktext' as a plain text.

I am using 'Render Component Content' and 'Default Component Template Finish Actions' template building blocks in my Dynamic component Template.

When I run template builder it gives me the following output as JSON

```
   Values: [
 "test Title: <ul><li><a title="mylinktext" xlink:href="tcm:23-32245" xlink:title="mylinktext" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">mylinktext</a></li></ul>]
```

But it is not showing any link at CDA side..If anyone can help in that..Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if the target of that link is published - links only show if the target is available. Also - you tagged it as DXA, but you're using custom TBBs?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes target link is published

Comment: What anout a Page that this CP is on?

Answer (score 3):

If the hyperlink is removed in the rendered output, that implies that the link could not be resolved using the CD Linking APIs. See https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Mapping/DefaultRichTextProcessor.cs

Unfortunately, there is no logging for this situation in DXA (yet), but the fact that the HTML anchor tag is suppressed is a tell-tale sign.